# Coloring dates in a CalendarView

Tags: java, android, xml

I have been searching through stackoverflow and numerous other sites for more than a week to find a way to color certain days in a CalendarView containing events, but with no luck. The only color change described in the documentation is that of the focused date, and of the focused week.

I got a CalendarView with a setOnDateChangeListener that opens a dialog fragment where the user can add information and save it to a database. I would like to pull the dates with information from the database and show those days as colored.

Can anyone help me find a way to color days with registered events in the CalendarView?

Best regards
AppDroid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is because there is no such feature in CalendarView, you have to either find a 3rd party library that can display events on days or write your own calendar

Comment: That explains it. They really should add that feature. Thanks =)